# How to ask a user for an input and reverse that input

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

2. Reverse input numbers
   // Write the function reverseInput() that:

// * Asks the user for numeric values using prompt.
// * Finishes asking when the user enters a non-numeric value, an empty string, or presses “Cancel”.
// * Returns an array of the input numbers in reverse order.

// P.S. Zero is a valid number, please don’t stop the input on zero.

Tried a do/while loop but the biggest array I can get has a length of 2

```
let userInput 
let reverseArray = []
do {
    userInput = prompt('Enter a number')
    reverseArray.unshift(userInput)
} while(userInput == /\d*/){
    userInput = prompt('Enter a number')
    reverseArray.unshift(userInput) 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problem in your code

- `while (userInput === /\d*/)` is trying to match userInput with `/\d*/` string, if you meant to use it pattern for testing digits you need to use `test`
- `do{} while(condition)` block after while makes no sense ( this block is allowing you that second prompt even after you do while fails after first iteration )
- You need to have a condition to avoid adding non digit to reverseArray

```js
let userInput
let reverseArray = []
do {
  userInput = prompt('Enter a number')
  if(/^\d+$/.test(userInput)){
   reverseArray.unshift(+userInput)
  }
} while (/^\d+$/.test(userInput))

console.log(reverseArray)
```

You can simply use native method [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check whether userInput is digit or not

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called isNaN, which checks if the number is number or not. 
Here is the reference [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). Here is the sample code for the same problem, you can take a look.

```js
function reverseInput() {
  const reverseArray = [];
  let number = parseInt(prompt('Enter number'));

  while (!isNaN(number)) {
    reverseArray.unshift(number);
    number = parseInt(prompt('Enter number'));
  }

  console.log(reverseArray);
}

reverseInput()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple `while` will do:

```js
let userInput = prompt('Enter a number');
let reverseArray = [];
while (userInput != null && !isNaN(userInput) ) {
  reverseArray.unshift(+userInput);   
  userInput = prompt('Enter a number');
} 
console.log(reverseArray);
```

Comment: `userInput != null && !isNaN(userInput)` <-- for this +1